Necessity of the prime condition in mod $p$ irreducibility test
This is the statement of mod $p$ irreducibility test that I read in my abstract algebra book:

Let $p$ be a prime and suppose that $f(x) \in Z[x]$ with deg $f(x)
\geq 1$. Let $\overline{f} (x)$ be the polynomial in $Z_p[x]$ obtained
from $f(x)$ by reducing all the coefficients of $f(x)$ modulo $p$. If
$\overline{f}(x)$ is irreducible over $Z_p$ and deg $\overline{f}(x)$
= deg $f(x)$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible over $Q$.

The proof in my book goes by contradiction. Suppose $f(x)$ is reducible over $Q$, then $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ with $g(x), h(x) \in Z[x]$. Let $\overline{f}(x),  \overline{g}(x), \overline{h}(x)$ be the polynomials obtained by reducing all the coefficients modulo $p$. Since $\overline{f}(x) = \overline{g}(x) \overline{h}(x)$ and also deg $\overline{g}(x), \overline{h}(x) <$ deg $\overline{f}(x)$, contradicting the assumption that $\overline{f} (x) $ is irreducible over $Z_p$.
However, my concern is that the condition $p$ is a prime does not seem to be necessary in this argument. Isn't it for any module, $f(x)=g(x)h(x) \implies \overline{f}(x) = \overline{g}(x) \overline{h}(x)$?

If $p$ is not prime, the argument about degree does not hold.

For example $2x\cdot 3x=0\pmod 6$.

Since deg $f(x)$ = deg $\overline{f} (x)$, deg $\overline{g} (x) \leq$ deg $g(x) < $ deg $f(x)=$ deg $\overline{f} (x)$. The first inequality is guaranteed by the property of only reducing coefficients, while the second is guaranteed by the reducibility of $f(x)$ in $Q$. Why is this argument dependent on whether $p$ is prime?
